# Write to console "thinking process"

Tags: c#, console

I am having issues with a connection to my Db on a server, and when I use different connection strings, there is a delay, and other times there is not.

To clarify; I have executed the "Connect to Db" function which always returns `false`:

```
public bool DbConnect()
{
    try
    {
        mySqlConnect = new MySqlConnection(Database_MySQLDef.mySqlConnectionString);
        mySqlConnect.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Number + " - " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

As part of debugging , is there a way I can get the "thinking process" to write to Console?

**I do not want help with the Db connection, only the process log**

Comment: What is the mechanism you are using? ADO .NET connection or an ORM framework like NHibernate?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican ADO .NET

Comment: You should be able to use Event Tracing For Windows for this, refer to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/455562/Diagnosing-ADO-NET-with-ETW-Traces

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican Ah. I was hoping it would be a fair bit simpler than that. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write to the Console before each process starts.

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting x");
x.Start();
Console.WriteLine("x Complete");
Console.WriteLine("Starting y");
y.Start();
Console.WriteLine("y Complete");
// ... etc.
```

Another possibility is set a breakpoint and step through the execution or set a series of breakpoints before/after each process and continue debugging (if using Visual Studio or a supporting IDE).